# Chrome Extension in Selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to load a Chrome extension in selenium using the following

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_extension('candidate.ai-get-email,-salary,-social-link_v0.3.6.crx')
```

I'm getting the error 'Path to the extension doesn't exist'  What is the correct path to use for a Ubuntu 16 machine?

Comment: Try with the file path instead of the the file name.

Comment: I've tried `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/candidate.ai-get-email,-salary,-social-link_v0.3.6.crx`  and `/home/yourusername/.cache/google-chrome/candidate.ai-get-email,-salary,-social-link_v0.3.6.crx`   with same result

Comment: Have you tried with a simple and shorter name?

Comment: I've tried several variants but they're just guesses

Comment: seems weird that commas and periods would be in your chrome extension name. you sure you don't mean three different crx's?  `candidate.ai-get-email.crx`, `candidate-salary.crx`, and `candidate-social-link_v0.3.6.crx` or something

Comment: I've also tried that

Answer (score 0):

So my solution, and everyone else might have assumed I was already doing this, is that I've downloaded a copy of the crx into downloads and rather than trying to access the installed version, I access this.  By putting the full path to the file (which does have all the commas) it is working.